# Is there a tool to example all references in a solution and offer suggestions for NuGet packages

Tags: visual-studio-2015, reference, nuget, package

While upgrading an older VS solution to VS 2015, it complained about MVC v3 references and I was able to update them to v5.2.3 and also related ones, but that got me thinking, it would be nice to have a tool that analyzes all of the non-NuGet references in a solution and offers suggestions to be migrated to their equivalent NuGet packages.  This way, I can easily upgrade or downgrade as needed and have links to their corresponding NuGet profile pages. Is there such a tool, a quick googling did not turn up anything?  Maybe some pointers on how I can automate such an analysis?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t find such automate tools for Visual Studio and NuGet. But I suggest you could search the NuGet packages through Manage NuGet Packages based on the key word of the referenced assemblies.

For example, if you reference System.Web.Mvc dll in your project, please right-click your project to choose Manage NuGet Packages and search “MVC” in the NuGet page. Then it will list all MVC related packages and you need to choose the one that you needed.

Comment: Thanks, @Wendy.  That is what I have done, but I was hoping there is an automated way to do this on a solution.

Comment: Since I don't find such tools at present, I help you submit your requirement to GitHub. Please add your comments for this feedback: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3634